# cannot get z-index working

Tags: z-index

please help!
I cannot get it working, and i dont understand why.

It a simple code, but it just not working.

I want folder_image.png appear beneath folder.png thats all!
Thanks a lot!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .container {
        width:  136px;
        height: 201px;
        background: url(http://s-ola.me/img/folder.png) no-repeat;
        z-index: 2;
                    position:relative;
    }

    .folder {
        width:  136px;
        height: 101px;
        background: url(http://s-ola.me/img/folder_image.png) no-repeat;
        z-index: 1;
                    position:relative;
    }

    .text {

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="folder"></div>
    <div class="text">text</div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this

```
<div class="folder" style="{z-index: 2};">
```

and take it out of the CSS

Answer (score 0):

I made this solution but i dont like it. It didnt answered on my question.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    #test{z-index:-10; position:relative;}
    .container {
        width:  136px;
        height: 201px;
        background: url(http://s-ola.me/img/folder.png) no-repeat;
        position: relative;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

     .folder {
        width:  136px;
        height: 101px;
        background: url(http://s-ola.me/img/folder_image.png) no-repeat;
        z-index:-1;
        position:relative;
    }
    .text {
 margin:0 auto;
 position:relative;
 margin-left:40px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="folder"></div>
        <div class="text">text</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can any one tell me why this work?

     .container {
   width:  136px;
   height: 201px;
   background: url(http://s-ola.me/img/folder.png) no-repeat;
   position: relative;
   margin:0 auto;
  }

   .folder {
   width:  136px;
   height: 101px;
   background: url(http://s-ola.me/img/folder_image.png) no-repeat;
   z-index:-1;
   position:relative;
  }

And if i add z-index to .container it stop working?
I need to add z index to container as well because i use it in context with other elements.

Please advice

Comment: I need to make another "container" (id="test") and let him index i want . Why? Why not to container class itself. Please can someone explain it? Tons of thanks